# $_SESSION not available when using jqUploader

Tags: php, jquery

I am using PHP and jQuery for an uploader. I am having a huge problem though and would like some input as to how best handle these two together.

I am using a PHP session variable that I am using to change the filename after the jquery uploader has finished. The jquery "url" is pointing to a PHP function that handles the actual upload. When I use the jquery uploader to upload an image, the session variable is never available. I'm assuming because the uploader itself is not using a session.

How can I resolve this issue? I need to have that session variable to change the filename.

**EDIT: I am using jqUploader**

Here is the code

```
function jqUploadPhoto( ){
    $picSize = '50550500';
    $picDir  = '/photos';

    $temp = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    ... substr()... convert old name to new name

    $file = $_SESSION['name'].$ext; // This is set and can be echoed when this func is used from a browser. Not available in JQ

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file) == false){ // This dies because the filename isn't available.
      echo 'NOTOK';
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if we knew specifically which 'uploader'.

Comment: Hi mkoistinen, I posted up top. Thanks.

Comment: A bit of code would help too :)

Comment: How are you setting and retrieving the variable in the session?

Comment: Please have a look at my edits.

Comment: Maybe you forgot session_start()? Where you initialize $_SESSION['name']? Maybe temp file should be $temp = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Uploadify.

**The problem**

Your browser makes a request to your site, the session is started and a cookie containing your session ID is set.

You then make an upload using Flash, note that Flash is not your browser and it acts as a new request. So a new session id is created and a new cookie is created, giving you two different sessions.

**The solution**

I got around this by setting the session id in the page, eg. in a hidden input and appening this session id to the request when Flash makes the upload. You need to detect this session id when you upload and set it using `session_id()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php . This will then replicate the session that the browser created.

Hope that helps.